# How to add random colors to random circles

Tags: python

I need to get a different colors filled in for the different size of the circles each time when I run the code.

```
from graphics import*
from random import*
from time import*

circle_x=0
circle_y=0
colors =0

#Graphics Window
def main():
    win = GraphWin("Bubbles", 500,500)
    message = Text(Point(250,200),"Click anywhere to continue")
    message.draw(win)
    win.getMouse()
    message.undraw()
main()    

#Create Circle
def create():
    win = GraphWin("Bubbles", 500,500)
    for i in range (4):

    # Creating a random point for the x of the circle
        circle_x = randint(50,450)

    #Creating a random point for the y of the circle
        circle_y = randint(0,100)

        p = Point(circle_x,circle_y)

        radius_x = randint(3,20)
        c = Circle(p,radius_x)

        colors = ("salmon","red","blue","green","purple","orange","yellow")
        fill = choice (colors)

        c.draw(win)
```

I have done this far, but somehow the color does not get filled in.
I need to use `choice`.

Comment: Sorry for nitpicking, but: Why have you commented above your function when you could have called it `create_circle`?

Comment: include your imports in your code.  did you import from the `random` module, the `turtle` module?
did you do exclusive imports?

Comment: @0TTT0 I have edited it. I prefer not to use turtle.

Comment: as long as we can see what you DID import, we can help

Comment: Don’t do wildcard imports. It makes it impossible for anyone unfamiliar with the APIs you are using to keep track of which function comes from where.

Answer (score 1):

```
colors = ("salmon","red","navy","steelblue","wheat","darkorange","yellow")
        fill = choice (colors)
        c.setFill(fill)
        c.draw(win)
```

Solved the problem!